# VSCode on Ubuntu not giving the option to compile with gcc

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get vscode to work with a c project but for some reason when I try to run it, it only gives this option. There is no option to compile with gcc or anything.

[image]

I may be being stupid but I cant find anything on it. When I look in launch.json, there is no configurations and none of the options under add configuration apply.

I have used vscode on this pc before and I don't think I have changed anything so no idea why it's just become an issue. It also doesn't work in workspaces that have worked in the past.

I have the c/c++ plugin installed and gcc is downloaded on the computer (gcc --version works). Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu and not getting the option to compile with GCC, it's likely that the C/C++ extension is not installed or properly configured. Here are the steps you can follow to fix this issue:

1. Open Visual Studio Code and go to the Extensions Marketplace by clicking on the Extensions icon in the left sidebar.
2. Search for "C/C++" in the search bar and click on the C/C++ extension from Microsoft.
3. Click on the Install button to install the extension.
4. After the installation is complete, restart Visual Studio Code.
5. Open your C/C++ project or file in Visual Studio Code.
6. Go to the Run tab in the left sidebar and click on "Add Configuration".
7. Select "C++ (GDB/LLDB)" from the list of options.
8. This will create a launch.json file in your workspace. Open the file and set the "preLaunchTask" to "C/C++: g++ build active file".
9. Save the launch.json file.
10. Now you should be able to compile your C/C++ code using the "C/C++: g++ build active file" task.

That's it! By following these steps, you should now be able to compile your C/C++ code with GCC in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu.

Comment: I dont see an option to add configuration in the run tab

Comment: try to juggle steps provided above, and try to figure out where that option is. also any how you have to get that plugin installed. that is your answer

Comment: ok well thanks for your help. the strangest thing is the plugin is installed as far as I can tell but ill mess with it